# Mirror grid in xaml/wpf into another xaml/wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

So basically I have a grid name 'gridSeatPlan' with buttons on it which allow the user to select. Is it possible for me to display the result that had been selected by the user into a second window which will be display on the second monitor?

I'm using code below but didn't get the mirror of the grid on the MainMenu. May I know which part did I done it wrong?

```
<Rectangle>
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=gridSeatPlan}"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

This is the code I use to show the form for the second monitor

```
If dualScreenSeatPlan = 2 Then
    Dim screen As Screen
    screen = Screen.AllScreens(dualScreenSeatPlan - 1)
    If Screen.AllScreens.Length > 1 Then
       FormSeatPlanDual = New frmSeatPlan_DualMirror
       BaseForm.ParentSeatPlanDual = FormSeatPlanDual
       FormSeatPlanDual.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
       FormSeatPlanDual.Location = screen.WorkingArea.Location
       FormSeatPlanDual.TopMost = True
       FormSeatPlanDual.Show()
    End If
ElseIf dualScreenSeatPlan = 1 Then
   Dim screen As Screen
   screen = Screen.AllScreens(dualScreenSeatPlan - 1)
   If Screen.AllScreens.Length > 1 Then
       FormSeatPlanDual = New frmSeatPlan_DualMirror
       BaseForm.ParentSeatPlanDual = FormSeatPlanDual
       FormSeatPlanDual.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
       FormSeatPlanDual.Location = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Location
       FormSeatPlanDual.TopMost = False
       FormSeatPlanDual.Show()
End If
```

Comment: Yes this can be done via binding if you provide us your code we and some more useful information we can actually help

Comment: @DenisSchaf thanks for the reply. I've try to do it with visualbrush but didn't get the result to mirror on the second monitor. I'm using 
        <Rectangle>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=gridSeatPlan}"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>

Comment: welcome to stack overflow I see you are new here. Please add the code to your question by editing it. Mark it and format it as code so it is readable for others

Comment: @DenisSchaf I'm sorry cus I'm still a newbie here. I edited my question and put in the code.

Comment: no problem we all started at one point! but where is the grid `gridSeatPlan` you were talking about?